# C Program - About Sizeof and Constant Used Together

Tags: c, arrays, constants, sizeof

Below is the code I am having issues with. I understand constants and believe I understand the sizeof function but must be missing something. Here is what I have tried to do to solve on my own:
- `printf` statement with TOTAL_ELEMENTS as the `%d` - it returns 7
- `printf` statement of TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2  - it returns 5 (as expected)
- substitute 5 in the for loop - loop runs correctly
- initialize a global int variable of any name and set it equal to `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))`. Then used the variable in the for loop where TOTAL_ELEMENTS would go - again the loop runs correctly.

So (at least in my head), it has to be something involving both the constant and the sizeof function - I'm positive the array/array[0] also plays a part but through testing and substitution I can't figure out what the issue is. I have read up on the sizeof function as well as constants to no avail. I have tried searching but have gotten no where as I'm not fully certain what I'm searching for. I don't necessarily need answers but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
    int d;

    for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
        printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is the compiler I am using; it should display all elements of the array but all that happens when I attempt to run it is it runs and ends with no printed output.

Comment: okay; I copied the code into ideone.com into the C compiler/executor and it comes up as well with no output. However when I change the code as listed in the original description it works as expected; still unsure.

Comment: I am getting the same result... No output. The only way to have expected output is to assign `int dmax = (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);` and change the loop to `for(d=-1;d <= dmax;d++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to `sizeof`. this is because of the comparing signed with unsigned value. In your code , `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` has an unsigned value , but `d` is a signed variable. therefore , `for` condition will compare 5 with 0xFFFFFFFF and 5 is less than 0xFFFFFFFF then it is false always!
For example :

```
int main()
{
    int d;
    unsigned int e = 5;
    for (d = -1; d <= e; d++)
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

It do not print any things! , same as your code.

Comment: You can force a signed comparison by casting to `int` in the loop `for(d=-1;d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)`.

Comment: Thank all of you! That was a major help.